MCP39F521, a Triac (T610), Load on Neutral & Measuring V and I
I'm trying to build a AC “power bar” with metering per “outlet”. The 2 most interesting chips I found are the Microchip MCP39F521 and the Allegro ACS37800. Due to costs, I've chosen the former. The MCU is an ESP32 (C6 module).
Microchip has a “Typical Application Circuit” in the data-sheet, showing I+ & I- coming from a 2 mili-Ohm shunt on “L”.

They also provide a development board, with schematics as well (). However, on the Dev board, the shunt is installed off of “N”.
In a single load circuit, I figure this is basically the same (6 of 1, half-a-dozen of the other).

Q1: Am I correct in assuming it doesn't matter where the measurements come from with a single load?
Now for the part I'm confusing myself with:
Using a triac to switch “outlets” on/off, for noise reasons, etc., most applications put the load on N and switch L (or, a kind of high-side switch?). My understanding of AC is that N carries everything back to the source. So, if I were to use 4 MCP39F521s (the limit to their I2C Addressing), and each load is on Neutral, would they all measure the same (total load), or can one expect differences depending on “where” in the circuit it's measured? In my circuit, I'm measuring between the Load and the Triac controlling it on N, something like this over-simplified drawing (my shunts are on the yellow highlighted lines):

Q2: With multiple loads, will my measurements be for individual loads or total load?
Q3: In Microchip's drawings, they use 2×499 kΩ resistors in series to V, each rated for 0.75 W. Is this due to power dissipation? UL Cert (no SPOF)? Cost? E.g. could I use 3×332 kΩ resistors at a 1/2 watt each? (assuming it's for power dissipation).
Q4: Following Q3, does one need to worry about current in the V measurement circuit? E.g. instead of a voltage divider, could one use a transformer to step-down the voltage to within the 2v+/- the ADC can handle? NOTE: This is not something I intend to do, rather I'm just trying to connect the dots between concepts.
And finally, an opinion question: if one had experience with both the ACS37800 & the MCP39F521, which would you choose and why?
Note that the oversimplified drawing above is due to my overly-complicated schematic, which is barely helpful to me. I'm in the process of improving it, and can share it, if needed.

There’s some Chinese metering chips that are much cheaper.  Triacs have leakage current that can upset some devices with switchedmode supplies. The Chinese ‘smart’ plugs use relays. Have a look at the Tasmota project - see what devices it supports to get an idea of what is used in the cheap WiFi ‘smart’ devices.

@Kartman - Indeed. I'd previously built some pseudo-smart plugs using relays. However, I noticed a few reactive loads welded the relay contacts closed, and the "10A/250V" ratings are strictly for resistive loads. The relays in question were the "Sonegal 5V" things that are all over Aliexpress. I upgraded to Omron and Panasonic relays which suffered less, but still suffered. Eventually I found that the 12v & 24v variants performed much better, but I didn't want multi power rails. I'll have to keep my eye on the leakage (measurements should help)

Q1. Current flows in a loop. Thus whether you measure on the active or neutral makes no difference. It makes a big difference to your circuit though. The metering chip will not withstand mains voltage across it, so be aware of the 0V reference point for the ic.
Q2. Again, current flows in a loop. Draw your loops and you have your answer. In short - your diagram should measure individual loads.
Q3. Resistors have a voltage rating. At a guess, your average 1/2 Watt through hole resistor is around 200VDC. Depending on your mains voltage, you might want to have 500+V rating. Either use a more expensive high voltage resistor or a number of cheaper std ones in series.
Q4. You can use a current transformer if you so desire. A shunt resistor is smaller and cheaper if you aren’t concerned with isolation.
No use asking an opinion if you haven’t specified your requirements. My requirements could be totally different to yours, so my opinion would be useless or misleading for you.
As I mentioned in my comment, I’d be looking at some Chinese ones if you’re not concerned about precision and they’re dead cheap.
Do you realise you can probably buy something that is ‘off the shelf’ that does what you want cheaper and better? Most of these WiFi smart devices can have open source code loaded onto them. As an example I have a RGB light bulb with a VIC20 emulator baked in that is based on Tasmota.
Further info - as I’ve mentioned, triacs ‘leak’. This gives a few mA of current with the device turned of. This may be a safety issue. As well, with loads like a led light, the leakage slowly charges up the capacitor in the light. When the voltage on the capacitor gets high enough the led briefly lights then the process repeats.
Triacs aren’t generally as robust as a relay. A momentary overload can damage them. To protect from this you need a very high speed fuse which tends to be very expensive. A standard fuse is of little use. Circuit breakers are slower still.
A T610 triac is a bit wimpy if you want to switch 10A. Something like a BTA41-600 might be more suitable.
You’d also need a transistor to get more drive current than the esp32 would provide. It would help the esp32 survive if the triac fails.
Other choices are two SCRs back to back. SCRs will usually have a better I2T rating. More I2T means the more likely the device will survive an overload. The ‘better’ solid state relays have this configuration.
For relays I would suggest an Omron G2R 16A or NAIS JM series. These have Chinese equivalents. Yes, you’d want to use 12 or 24V versions.
Designing pcb’s for high currents can be a challenge. A common technique is to run a bus bar for the high current paths. This can be as simple as soldering on thicker copper wire.
Other options are automated circuit breakers. These can be controlled electronically.

Brilliant! Thank you!

Brilliant! Thank you!
Regarding the off-the-shelf stuff - yes. My purpose is more about learning and being able to say, "I built that".
Fair point on opinions. My initial requirement was "measure power on mains at home", followed by cost, followed by interface (i2c). Both seem to do this. Now, "ease of use" feels like an added requirement. Perhaps I'll try 2 designs so I can have a comparison.
Also tried to upvote but I don't have enough points.
